# How to exchange data between two layer in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have Layer A with the skill button and Layer B with the plyer sprite, what I need is that, when I touch the skill button and the plyer will use the skill.
How can I let the Layer B know that when I touch the button?
Is there anyone can show me with simple demo?

Comment: Not clear enough. could you paste your sample code? is your two layer in the same scene? which layer is created first?                           To make it simple, you can save a pointer pointed to Layer B in Layer A, and then you can call Layer B functions.                             To make it nice and elegant, Use a delegate class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is use a Singleton structure. In example, do a DataModule, create getters and setters, and call them using the static pointer to write or read data.

Comment: I think what he need might not be just simple data passing, its more like function pointer. Otherwise he could just use CCUSerDefault if there is not so much data.

Comment: Thx for reply, i did it last night with singleton, your advice help me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: Then set the answer as correct :D Green tick under the number 1